# Facebook Chat API - Python App Engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm trying to use the Facebook chat API in my web service(AppEngine Python). I found some code on line, but any of them help me to make it work.

This is the code I'm using, but don't work. What I am doing wrong?

```
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            response = dict()

            msg = "hello world"
            jid = "myID@chat.facebook.com"
            pwd = "passwd"
            server = "chat.facebook.com"
            recipient="targetID@chat.facebook.com"
      try:
            jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(jid)
            cl = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=["always"])

            if not cl.connect((server, 5222)):
                response['Error Connection'] = 'Not connected.'

            elif cl.auth(jid.getNode(), pwd) == None:
                response['Error Auth'] = 'Authentication failure.'
            else:
                cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(recipient, msg, "chat"))
                cl.disconnect()
                response['status'] = 'success'
        except:
            response['status'] = 'failed'

        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know the facebook api, but probably you have to put the facebook Id on recipient targetId.
You have to put the user ID that you want to send the message.

recipient="facebookUserID@chat.facebook.com"

Comment: of course I changed the "targetID" to my friend ID and in "passwd" I put my password in facebook and in "myID" I changed to my ID in FB